# How to generate the cartesian product of an array with itself in C?

Tags: c, combinations, cartesian-product

I'm having trouble trying to figure out a way to get the cartesian product of an array and specifying how many times.
This is an example of what I want to do (pseudocode):

```
int arr = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int n = 2;

int[][] result = cartesian(arr, n);
//result would be {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 0},..., {3, 3}}

n = 3;
result = cartesian(arr, n);
//since n is now 3, result would be{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1},..., {3, 3, 3}} and so on.
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Ma66oTo What is {0, 0}, ? If it is a single value then why do you want to declare a two-dimensional array?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is recursively. If you have a sequence of size N and you'd like to find the Kth order Cartesian product of it with itself, there are N^K elements to be generated. Here's some pseudocode to get you started:

```
generate_helper(A, k, C, S):
    if k = 0:
        C.append(S)
    else:
        for each a in A:
            S.push(a)
            generate_helper(A, k - 1, C, S)
            S.pop()

generate(A, k):
    C := {} -- Empty collection of sequences of order k.
    S := {} -- Empty sequence of elements
    generate_helper(A, k, C, S)
    return C
```

Here, this will recursively generate all the elements. To generate the sequences of length k, we first pick an element, fix it, and generate all possible sequences of length k-1 starting with the chosen element. If we do this for all elements in the sequence, we'd have generated every element in the Cartesian product.

Now, since you have the pseudocode, I trust it should be routine to implement it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion :) In C++11 you would do it like this (where `cartesian()` is the function you want)

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void add_all_once(deque<deque<int>>& result, const deque<int>& vec, int which) {
    for (decltype(vec.size()) i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        deque<int> to_be_pushed = result[which];
        to_be_pushed.push_back(vec[i]);
        result.emplace_back(std::move(to_be_pushed));
    }
}

deque<deque<int>> cartesian(const deque<int>& vec, int n) {
    deque<deque<int>> cartesian_product;
    decltype(vec.size()) size = vec.size();

    // Fill 1 dimension
    for (decltype(vec.size()) i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cartesian_product.push_back(deque<int>({vec[i]}));
    }

    // Fill all possibilities once
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        decltype(cartesian_product.size()) current_size = cartesian_product.size();

        for (decltype(cartesian_product.size()) j = 0; j < current_size; ++j) {
            add_all_once(cartesian_product, vec, j);
        }

        for (decltype(cartesian_product.size()) j = 0; j < current_size; ++j) {
            cartesian_product.pop_front();
        }
    }


    return cartesian_product;
}

int main() {
    deque<int> vec = {1, 2, 3};

    auto n = 2;
    auto return_val = cartesian(vec, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < return_val.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < return_val.at(i).size(); ++j) {
            cout << return_val[i][j] << ' ';
        } cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is great, any idea how to could implement this in C?

Comment: Hmmmm... I have not programmed much C but maybe you could use some container libraries similar to a deque that are out there?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to generate the k-fold Cartesian product of a set with itself. This is basically equivalent to the [k-combinations of the set with repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition). There is a simple algorithm [from Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions#C) implementing this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * donuts[] = { "iced", "jam", "plain", "something completely different" };

long choose(int * got, int n_chosen, int len, int at, int max_types)
{
        int i;
        long count = 0;
        if (n_chosen == len)
        {
                if (!got) return 1;

                for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                        printf("%s\t", donuts[got[i]]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                return 1;
        }

        for (i = at; i < max_types; i++)
        {
                if (got) got[n_chosen] = i;
                count += choose(got, n_chosen + 1, len, i, max_types);
        }
        return count;
}

int main()
{
        int chosen[3];
        choose(chosen, 0, 2, 0, 3);

        printf("\nWere there ten donuts, we'd have had %ld choices of three\n",
                choose(0, 0, 3, 0, 10));
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
iced    iced

iced    jam
iced    plain
jam     jam
jam     plain
plain   plain

Were there ten donuts, we'd have had 220 choices of three
```

You can easily modify this to work on arrays of numbers instead of C-style strings.